# google sheet copy cells to another tab according to 2 values in 2 different cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a tab called "Input" where i input the information of a bill: Code(D5), attribution(E5), date(F5), bill#(G5), description(H5), compagny(I5) and amount(J5).
I have 2 tabs called "010" and "020" inside these tabs are 3 sections of rows for the attribution: Contract, Endorsement and Extra.
I want to copy/insert F5:J5 from the imput tab below the specific section of attribution specified in (E5) in the correct code tabs specified in (D5). when the script is triggered

I had this working with excel but I'm new in google apps script, used to work with vba

thanks

[Input tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf0kJ.png)

[010 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuAqR.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputsh = sh.getSheetByName("Input");
  var attribution = inputsh.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var code = inputsh.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var data = inputsh.getRange("F5:J5").getValues();
  
  //determine which Sheet we will write the data.
  var sheetName = '';
  if(code == 10){
    sheetName = '010';
  }else if(code == 20){
    sheetName = '020';
  }
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var attributePos = sheet.getRange("A7:A").getValues();

  // While the last element is a '',
  while(attributePos[attributePos.length-1][0] === ''){ 
    // Remove that last element
    attributePos.pop();                  
  }

  if(attribution == 'Contrat'){
    attribution = 'Contract';
  }
  //find the position of attribute
  var pos = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < attributePos.length-1; i++){
    //This part will check if the attribution in input sheet matches the label in the Column A of 010 or 020 sheets. This will determine which section to append the data. 
    if(attributePos[i][0] == attribution){
      var ctr = 0;
      for(var j = i; j < attributePos.length-1; j++){  
        //Find all empty cells, this will determine if the current cell is the last row of section.
        if(attributePos[j][0] == ''){
          ++ctr;
          //Stop loop if the counter is equal to 2 or last row of data in section.
          if(ctr == 2){
            pos = j;
            break;
          }
        }
      } 
      break;
    }
  }

  var newDataRow = 7 + pos;
  //Insert empty row
  sheet.insertRowBefore(newDataRow).activate();
  //Insert data
  sheet.getRange(newDataRow,1, 1, 5).setValues(data);
}
```

**Test Data:**

Input Sheet:

[image]

010 & 020 Sheet:

[image]

**After executing the code:**

[image]

### References:

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thks see answer

Comment: @MarcBlanchette - To answer your inquiries below. I mistakenly thought that `Contrat` is a misspelled word for `Contract`. I updated my answer to accommodate the issue and added comment to explain how the script determine which section to append the data. For the formatting, I would like to support your but the formatting is different topic from the post. Kindly create another post or look for a similar topic regarding retaining of formats. This is to avoid confusion when a community member bump into this post.

Comment: its a french thing, Contrat is actually Contract in french. I deleted row 6 and it works had to do some editing but the script do what I was hoping for.  Thanks alot